# Generate .CRT php openssl

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

**I need generate .crt in php from a previous upload .csr file**

I have a php page, i upload the file .csr

```
<?php
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
      $nombreArchivo = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

    // RUTA DEL SSL
    $ssl_path = getcwd();
    $ssl_path = preg_replace('/\\\/','/', $ssl_path);

    // ARCHIVO DE CONFIGURACIÓN SSL
    $config = array("config" => "$ssl_path/openssl.cnf");

    $csr = 

    //CRT
    $sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, 365, $config);
    openssl_x509_export_to_file($sscert,  "server.crt",  FALSE );  

?>
```

I need to assign the content of file to the var $csr and the private key, after i need generate .crt and export.

Comment: So what problem are you having? You have told us what you want to do, but not what the actual problem is that is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: @MikeBrant I need to generate .CRT from a previos upload .csr file

Comment: Yes understood, but what problem are you having in being able to do that?

Comment: @MikeBrant how i can assign the content of the file to the var $csr ??

Comment: Have you not been able to Google or look through PHP.net to arrive at `file_get_contents()`, or is that not working for some reason?

Comment: @MikeBrant thanks Mike, i resolve the get content of file. Now i need generate a certificate (.crt) from a previos .csr file. I'm using this function openssl_csr_sign($csr, $cacert, $privkey, 365); but i don't have a private key, i need to find a method to generate a crt without the private key

Comment: Are you trying to generate a self-signed certificate?  Or are you trying to generate a certificate signed by a CA?  The null parameter in openssl_csr_sign leads me to believe you want a self-signed certificate.  If that is the case, you'll need to use the same private key that was used to generate the CSR.  If you do NOT want a self-signed certificate and want a certificate signed by a CA, then you'll need the private key from that CA and you'll need to pass in the CA cert instead of null.  See the PHP documention for [openssl_csr_sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-sign.php).